# Deployed application (Oracle 11g, VB.NET 2015 and Crystal Reports) cannot connect to database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, deployment, client, windows-10

I'm developing an application using Oracle 11g, VB.NET 2015 and Crystal Reports on Windows 10. I created a package and installed it on another PC on same network. The package is running fine but unable to connect to the database... Can you give advise/tips how I can deploy the application on client/server, my current network environment is Windows 10.